# How To Put Navigation Bar In Separated Borders?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble on how to put the navigation buttons in separate borders like the following (this one was without flexbox):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mABM9.png

I need help with it using flexbox so I could improve on my website by adding necessary features. If anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(49, 28, 240), rgb(62, 131, 235));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Heading */

.container1{ /* Contains All Contianers */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#header{
    font-family: Impact;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.418);
    padding: 25px;
    flex: 1;
}

#heading_Text{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

/* Navigation */

.container2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#nav{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- Created By Joshua Wong -->
        <!-- Updated On: 2/28/2021 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container1">
            <div id="header">
                <h2 id="heading_Text">Sample Website</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2">
            <div id="nav">
                <a href="index.html" id="home" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
                <a href="#" id="info">Information</a>
                <a href="#" id="gallery">Gallery</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the `#nav` div a flex container and have each `<a>` be one fourth of the width. See below, my additions are at the end. You can customize visuals to your liking. The key part is the use of flex in the parent.

If you don't know how many items there will be in the second row, consider `flex-grow` to automatically grow the `a`s.

I quite like this as a tutorial and reference about flex in css: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. It has some nice examples.

Also note that your `.container2` div is unnecessary and can be removed.

To adjust the padding, use `padding` css property on the `a` tags.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(49, 28, 240), rgb(62, 131, 235));
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#header{
    font-family: Impact;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.418);
    padding: 25px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#heading_Text{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

/* Navigation */

/*.container2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}*/

#nav{
    text-align: center;
    /* My additions start here*/
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#nav > a {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- Created By Joshua Wong -->
        <!-- Updated On: 2/28/2021 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h2 id="heading_Text">Sample Website</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="index.html" id="home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
            <a href="#" id="info">Information</a>
            <a href="#" id="gallery">Gallery</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need container2 so it can move it under the heading. Unless you have an alternative solution?

Comment: @Antdog0101 I've updated the snippet to show how you can achieve this without the duplicate containers. DIVs are by default full width so you can do this with just two containers, one for the top title and another for the links row below it.

Comment: what does the > mean in the selector? (e.x. #nav > a)

Comment: In this case, it means all ``a`` elements inside ``#nav``. For your use you could just use ``a`` as the selector and leave out the > but you're probably going to have other ``a`` elements on the page as well.

Comment: @SedkiSghairi I'm afraid you're mistaken. The > selector selects EVERY one of them, not just the first. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Try with bootstrap. It will be very easy and responsive as well like below :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Information</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```